# How to make a " dart wrapper for MuPdf "?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, mupdf

I want to use MuPdf for viewing documents from my Dart code. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this plugin help you? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

Comment: I actually want to make a plug in like this. ..